# How to delete collapsing toolbar in android

Tags: android

Right now I have collapsing toolbar from material design.

I want to change it to default or material action bar.

Can i do it from menu.xml or any alternative way?

My code is bellow.
If you need more code, ask me.

Thanks a lot.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mateoj.popularmoviesdemo.MovieDetailActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_movie_detail"/>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Menu.xml code is bellow:

```
 **menu.xml**



 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.demo.mtin.mtin.MovieDetailActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. Remove CollapsingToolbarLayout and set your desing to toolbar after that use **setActionBar(yourtoolbar)** method.
More information read this: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar